# How to convert CFReadStreamRef to NSInputStream?

Tags: ios, sockets, network-programming

```
    - (void)connection:(NSString*)serviceName forIpAddress:(NSString *)ipAddress
       forPort:(NSString *)portNo
  {
if(inputStream && outputStream)
    //[self close];

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",ipAddress];

NSURL *website = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

if (!website) {
    NSLog(@"%@ is not a valid URL", website);
}
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)[website host], [portNo
                                                                       intValue], &readStream, &writeStream);
CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket,
                        kCFBooleanTrue);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket,
                         kCFBooleanTrue);
inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
[self open];
```

}

Getting ARC errors at NNString, NSInputStream,NSoutputStream.
Error says..Cast of c pointer type CFreadStreamRef to c pointer type NSinput stream needs bridging cast.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385093/convert-cast-cfreadstreamref-to-nsinputstream-ios5

Comment: (Make sure to include the *verbatim* error message, not some incorrect representation.)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSInputStream *inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;
NSOutputStream *outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
```

See [Setting Up Socket Streams](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html) programming guide.